# Элементы видят флоаты внутри формы, как?

Tags: html, вёрстка, google-chrome, form, float

4 инпута зафлоачены, за ними идет кнопка без очистки флоата и почему-то она их видит, и не только кнопка... Почему так?

```css
form {
    width: 300px;
}

input {
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    outline: none;
    background: #ffffff
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-family: "PT Sans Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #000000;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 106px;
    padding: 7px 15px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}

input:nth-child(2n) {
    margin-right: 0;
}

.btn {
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #000000;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-family: "PT Sans Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 33px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-right: 16px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<form class="appointment-form" action="#" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="date" placeholder="дата">
  <input type="text" name="time" placeholder="время">
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="ваше имя">
  <input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="телефон">
  <button type="submit" class="btn">Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Когда ты используешь свойство `float: left;` это означает, что это элемент выравнивается по левому краю, а другие элементы (такие как текст, например) будут обтекать его по правой стороне. И так как ширина формы фиксированная то кнопка переноситься вниз.

Проблема с float заключается в том, что если элемент имеет `float:left;` или `float: right;` то он не влияет на высоту родителя. В данном случае нужно применять очистку флоата

Comment: так я это знаю как отче наш, но почему то кнопка button ведет себя так как будто я задал ей clear both, а я не задавал, и в инспекторе нет ничего

Comment: @NikolLakin, а как она должна себя вести? какое поведение Вы ожидаете от неё?

Comment: она не должна видеть флоатов, тоесть ее content box должен растягиватся от самого верха родителя, а сам контент жить под инпутами

Comment: как я понял кнопки видят любые флоаты, для них clear both не нужен

Comment: Это не относиться только к кнопке, это особенность работы флоатов. Если хотите, чтобы интпуты "жили" под кнопкой то используйте свойство position

Comment: Если в форме есть один зафлоаченый инпут, то тег p его не видит, и маргин считаеться не от инпута, а тег button его видит и маргин работает почему так?